# change formatting of a word within a string

Tags: jquery, joomla

I have a joomla menu list which has items like 'be different', 'be the best' etc

Every time the string 'be' is in the text I need to make it bold.

I was planning on using jQuery. I have looked at expressions like match, indexof or using regex but got stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this way

```
$('#Menu').html($('#Menu').html().replace(/(be )/g, '<strong>be </strong>'));
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mN8zw/10/)

Comment: why doesn't it work if I do this: $('#Menu').html().replace(/(be )/g, '<strong>be </strong>')???